# Every env variables work except MONGO_CLUSTER in SPRINGBOOT app using maven dependencies

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

## Maven dependency used

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

## applications.properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=${env.MONGO_DATABASE}
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://${MONGO_USER}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_CLUSTER}
```

## Error :-

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-10-10T16:12:28.505+05:30 ERROR 20008 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception with message: An SRV host name '${MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at dev.mercifulsamurai.movies.MoviesApplication.main(MoviesApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception with message: An SRV host name '${MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SRV host name '${MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.<init>(ClusterSettings.java:594) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.<init>(ClusterSettings.java:50) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings$Builder.build(ClusterSettings.java:370) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.<init>(MongoClientSettings.java:957) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.<init>(MongoClientSettings.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.build(MongoClientSettings.java:600) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:50) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 23 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

## This works somehow but i should not be using it like this

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=${env.MONGO_DATABASE}
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://${MONGO_USER}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@cluster0.*******.mongodb.net
```

Comment: Those properties aren't prefixed with `env` like the first one.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have initialized all 4 of the variables in the .env file correctly but only the MONGO_CLUSTER doesn't work

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The first one is prefixed with `env`, which is the default prefix used by dotenv. THe others don't have this and are thus resolved from the actual environment NOT your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

remove `env.` from first line of properties file.